# ajaxcontroltoolkit missed when trying to republish published files on another machine or my local IIS

Tags: iis, ajaxcontroltoolkit, conflict

I have a published web application on specific server. I want to run the same application on another IIS server, but i get this error

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

[Exception is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB7x5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Report Viewer fixed it.
The problem was that my web.config was targeting .NET 2.0 and has some configuration related to .NET 2.0. I've updated the solution projects to target .NET 4.0 which need the report viewer dll in GAC folder or something global and that's what report viewer installer will do.